# SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider.GetUsersInRole(string roleName) encountered a role '0(.s|true' with unsupported original issuer type 'SecurityTokenService'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, claims-based-identity

Getting the following error message in the SharePoint 2010 ULS Logs when some custom code attempts to invoke `SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup()`:

```
SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider.GetUsersInRole(string roleName) encountered a role '0(.s|true' with unsupported original issuer type 'SecurityTokenService'.
```

Any ideas what would cause this? This is a Claims-Based-Authentication site and this code works fine on another server with Claims-Based-Authentication configured.

Answer (score 1):

Still have no idea what causes this issue, but the role `'0(.s|true'` is `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated Users` on SharePoint 2010 and `'Everyone'` on SharePoint 2013. Checking for this user and then avoiding the call to `SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup()` if it is this user will allow you to avoid the issue.